# JS: transform header and body array to single json

Tags: javascript

I want to transform 2 arrays into 1 final json object.
The first array contains the header data and the second one the body.
Each row of the body should be assigned to a column of the header.
This image illustrates the input and the expected output:

[image]

I'm using 3 nested loops to assign the data.
The keys are working but I'm stucked getting the correct data because somehow only data from the last body row are extracted.

There must be a minor thing, I'm missing in my code:

```js
const header = ['A','B','C','D']
const body = [
  ["A1","A2","A3","A4","A5","A6"],
  ["B1","B2","B3","B4","B5","B6"],
  ["C1","C2","C3","C4","C5","C6"],
  ["D1","D2","D3","D4","D5","D6"],
];

const json = [];

for (let y = 0; y < body[0].length; y++)
{
  const line = {};
  for(const hl of header)
  {
    for(const bo of body)
    {
      line[hl] = bo[y];
    }
  } 
  json.push(line);
}

console.log(json);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say your gut feeling is correct, but you're always replacing the column values with the values of the last column.

Plus, at least as I understand your drawing, you want an array of objects, where the key is the header and the value is the corresponding value, i.e. I understand you want `[{A:'A1', B: 'B1', C: 'C1', D: 'D1'}, …]` and not `[['A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1'], …]`. Correct?

Below is an approach using `[].map()` and `[].reduce()`, which, to me (who is used to this style of writing, I admit), makes it a lot clearer what happens:

```js
const header = ['A','B','C','D']
const body = [
  ["A1","A2","A3","A4","A5","A6"],
  ["B1","B2","B3","B4","B5","B6"],
  ["C1","C2","C3","C4","C5","C6"],
  ["D1","D2","D3","D4","D5","D6"],
];

console.log(body[0].map((_, row) =>
  header.reduce((json, key, col) => ({
    ...json,
    [key]: body[col][row]
  }), {})));
```

Comment: Thank you - I've come through a lot of array/obj questions with answers using map/reduce... They look always clean and are very short... for me it's just hard to understand what happens inside... must be some kind of magic :D